# Pan/Zoom painfully slow in IE8 RaphaelJS

Tags: internet-explorer-8, zooming, raphael, drag, pan

I have been working on getting this seat mapping chart for a while and have created a few iterations, and the problem I keep finding is when I get to IE8 the panning for this is way to slow and delayed.

What I have at this point to cut down on load time is created a png to replace my "strokes" since  I assume ie8 wanted to re-render each time I dragged the map.

I also added controls hoping to force IE8 users this option, but still there is a delay in the  pan, and if I can have users with IE8 (and ie7 if possible) still drag/pan without the controls and the respond time a little faster that would be great.

**[Here is my current JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knottAverage/ArKDp/29/)**

I am still a little green with JS so if you have any suggestions it would be much appreciated. (PS Chrome frame is awesome but **is not** a option for me)

**Update**

I have removed the original dragging function and replaced the code using jqueryui's draggable function. Martin had suggested to just drag the div, and not the Raphael elements. Doing so lets this thing fly in ie6-8 which is great, but then came my concern about scaling. What I was seeing before on zoom my paper element WxH would stay the same ratio, cutting off my drawing when it zoomed in. After digging through the Raphael documentation I came across paper.setSize. setSize was exactly what I needed to allow this project to move and groove in ie6-8 and pretty much conquer all browsers in its path.

So in short, using jqueryui's draggable and paper.setSize has cured my cross browser zoom n' pan blues.

Comment: So I am looking into .pair to hope this will somehow make it faster

Comment: *For anyone reading this* Based of my assumption to what Martin was suggesting, I have added jquery ui to the fiddle and attaching .draggable() to the Raphael element. Speed in ie8 panning has improved, but new issues appear with zooming slightly working.

[New JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knottAverage/ArKDp/31/)

Comment: MORE NEWS

At this point I have tried a few drag methods with jquery. All work great except for ie8, still having dragging issues not as smooth as I would want it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what can be seen in the Fiddle, you are triggering a new rendering of the image by calling `.translate()` inside of a `mousemove` event handler:

```
mapContainer.translate(currentMapPosX, currentMapPosY);
rsrGroupies.translate(currentMapPosX, currentMapPosY);
```

This approach is toxic for performance in all browsers, let alone IE8. When dealing with VML in IE8 you should consider that each and every DOM change inside the image will result in the image being rendered again. Doing that while panning will always be painfully slow.

I see that you are already using jQuery in your Fiddle. If you want to increase performance of your panning, you should consider doing the following:

1. Render the image in Raphaël exactly once for the current zoom level. Do not attempt to change transformations in your VML/SVG image at any point in time while panning.
2. With the `mousemove` implementation of panning you already have, move or scroll the HTML container that holds your VML/SVG image instead. Imagine a `<div>` with `overflow: hidden` and simply move the image inside relatively, or scroll to the appropriate position.

This will require some adjustment of your coordinate calculations, but it will improve your performance in all browsers.

Comment: Hey Martin, finally getting the chance to tackle this again. I just wanted to clarify. You are saying to to render the image raphael then say use #rsr.draggable(); am i correct im assuming this?

Comment: Also then should i use jquery top handle the zoom, will jquery be able to handle the zoom of those vectors in ie8?